# Prevent form_with from generating a parameter and submitting it (all by itself)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, form-with

When a `form_with` submits, it submits all the desired parameters, but also a parameter called "booking", and I have absolutely no idea where this parameter came from. It's not contained in the view, nor in the controller. It seems `form_with` is generating it from somewhere, but I have no idea how/why?

I could allow it as a `permit`ted parameter, to prevent an `Unpermitted parameter: :booking` error, and just ignore it, but I would prefer to know what's going on and remove the extraneous parameter.

Why is `form_with` generating an unwanted parameter, and how can I stop it from doing so?

```
  <%= form_with(url: '/booking-confirm', method: :post, local: false) do |f| %> 

  <br>Select a time:<br><br>
    <% days.each do |day, availabilities| %> 
      <% availabilities.each do |avail| %>
          <%= f.label avail.time_slot %> 
          <%= radio_button_tag(:time_slot, avail.time_slot) %><br>
        <% end %> 
        <hr>
      <% end %>
      
  <%= f.submit "Confirm!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

Notice there's no reference to any `booking` param anywhere in the code (the closest thing is `url: '/booking-confirm'`)

Comment: Is this request going to the `bookings_controller`? If so, this might be due to ParamsWrapper. Check [this blog post](https://medium.com/ruby-daily/params-wrapper-in-ruby-on-rails-30e7921f7704)

Comment: @AbM good suggestions, I have no model/controller called booking/s and in the controller that the form submits to, there is no action called booking/s

Comment: Could you post an example of what the params look like going to the controller?  Also, what is the controllers name that handles this submission? Just to verify, what you shared above is the whole form, correct?